# Sonar runner is not listing the CxxCppCheckSensor while runner is started

Tags: c++, sonarqube, cppcheck

I am new to sonar, i have installed sonarqube on RHEL 7 machine and its version is 5.1.1.
and the runner's version is 2.4.
I have four cpp related plugins, i tried with each one,

> sonar-cxx-plugin-0.9.4-RC3.jar sslr-cxx-toolkit-0.9.4-RC3.jar
>
> sonar-cpp-plugin-3.6.jar sonar-cpp-plugin-3.5.jar
>
> sonar-cxx-plugin-0.9.jar

nothing seems to be listing the Sensor CxxCppCheckSensor . i need this for integrating cppcheck with the sonar. my cppcheck version is `1.68`.
i have included `sonar.cfamily.cppcheck.reportPath = in my sonar.project.properties` file too.

Am I doing something wrong here ? Please help me out.

1.And do these cpp plugins needs license or trial key for proceeding?
2. Can cppcheck's xml report alone be viewed in sonar's dashboard?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

sonar-cpp-plugin correspond to the commercial plugin and of course needs a license, sonar.cfamily.cppcheck.reportPath property is only for the commercial plugin.

sonar-cxx-plugin correspond to the community C++ plugin and has different properties.

Do not mix the two different plugins and documentation, pick one and follow one documentation installing only one of them.